# Why do we not need to install the eslint plugins in our end user app, to use @vercel/style-guide?

Tags: javascript, eslint, vercel, eslint-plugin-react

This is a question about plugin modules resolution in ESLint, when using pnpm. There are many articles and answers about this online, I have read most of it.

I have also educated myself on pnpm's node_modules structure and ESLint's resolution algorithms. I still do not understand why we do not need to install the plugins used under the hood by the `@vercel/style-guide` module.

This is what the ESLint docs says about plugin resolution:

> 1. Plugins are resolved relative to the config file. In other words,
>    ESLint loads the plugin as a user would obtain by running
>    `require('eslint-plugin-pluginname')` in the config file.
> 2. Plugins in the base configuration (loaded by extends setting) are relative to the
>    derived config file. For example, if `./.eslintrc` has `extends: ["foo"]`
>    and the `eslint-config-foo` has `plugins: ["bar"]`, ESLint finds the
>    `eslint-plugin-bar` from `./node_modules/` (rather than
>    `./node_modules/eslint-config-foo/node_modules/`) or ancestor
>    directories. Thus every plugin in the config file and base
>    configurations is resolved uniquely.

`@vercel/style-guide` exposes some ESLint configs, like the react.js config, which in turn will `extend: plugin:eslint-plugin-react`, which in turn contains `plugin: { react }`.

With that in mind, it is safe to assume that when our application extends `@vercel/style-guide/react` is should be necessary to install the plugins it uses, i.e. `eslint-plugin-react` directly as a dependency of the end user app.

I tried it, and for some reason it is not necessary to install them.

Why is that? What am I not seeing about the resolution of these plugins?

Comment: What shows up when you use `npm ls` to see what package depends on any one ESLint plugin?

Comment: @rxgx Doing `pnpm la` will show the dependencies and devDependencies of the app. I do not think that adds any clarity around how ESLint plugin resolution is done. Unless I misunderstood you?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason it works without manually hoisting those packages.

The answer was that [pnpm's default setting for `public-hoist-pattern` is](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#public-hoist-pattern):

`['*eslint*', '*prettier*']`

As such, it is crucial not to overwrite that setting. If changing it, include the defaults as well. For instance:

```
public-hoist-pattern[]=*eslint*
public-hoist-pattern[]=*prettier*
public-hoist-pattern[]=*storybook*
```

---

**EDIT**

I found out that `@vercel/style-guide` uses a community package that changes the behavior of how ESLint resolves plugins, so that it no longer resolves them from the derived config, but instead from the config where the plugin is actually mentioned.

The Vercel team clarified it here: https://github.com/vercel/style-guide/issues/86#issuecomment-1924675205

The package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rushstack/eslint-patch